# Where to put assets in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode8

I have an Xcode 8 C++ project. Where do I put all the images and music so that I can then reference them directly like this: "image_folder//image_1.jpg"

Comment: I suggest you use the term "resources" and search the internet for "XCode c++ resources".

Comment: This is a question often asked...  Have a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409759/how-to-reference-to-images-and-other-objects-in-xcode-and-where-to-place-them-ph